# What is Mastercraft?

Tags: spycraft

I was a big fan of AEG's [Spycraft RPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spycraft). Then with Spycraft 2.0 the game was handed off to CraftyGames or something like that. They made FantasyCraft. Now there is talk of Spycraft 3rd Edition. With that many of the CraftyGames descriptions use the term **[Mastercraft](http://www.crafty-games.com/node/785)**. What is this exactly? I'm thinking its like WEG's [Masterbook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masterbook) in-house rules system or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "[Announcing MasterCraft](http://www.crafty-games.com/node/635)":

> When we at Crafty Games announced Fantasy Craft last fall the number one request was that it be a standalone product. People loved the idea of traditional adventure gaming with the powerful and versatile Spycraft system but they only wanted to use one book to make it happen. Plus, they worried about rules from what’s perceived to be a modern action-espionage product interlocking to create a different genre.
>   Simultaneously, we’ve been developing Henchman Edition, a lighter, faster, and sleeker version of the rules for the growing part of our fan base that want to use them but can’t quite wrap their heads around the full Spycraft 2.0 experience. The response on this product has been overwhelmingly positive but ultimately it’s yet another book you’d have to add to the expanding collection.
>   So we’ve decided to go another way, folding the basis for what would have become Henchman into all our future print products. From now on you’ll see a new logo on the back of Crafty books...
>
> The Mastercraft system lets us continue producing games with one of the strongest tactical rules systems on the market without conversion or adaptation. Every book, from Fantasy Craft to our street noir opus Ten Thousand Bullets to our space opera epic Farthest Star and beyond, will be expressly tailored to the genre at hand. Better yet, you’ll get everything you need to play — from character creation to skills to combat and building adventures — in one streamlined package.
>   Mastercraft material will be portable into Spycraft and vice-versa, and the License to Improvise will still be supported for those looking to get their hands dirty with a little development of their own. We’ll continue supporting Spycraft as well — our flagship isn’t going anywhere! Basically, it’s everything Crafty Games has always offered plus everything you’ve asked for and an upgraded, polished new rules set to boot!
>   Welcome to a new era. An era powered by Mastercraft.

So Spycraft 3rd Edition will contain the full Mastercraft rules it looks like.

Comment: After reading all that it's still a bit unclear.

Comment: @mxyzplk The rules revision to Spycraft 2.0 will be published under the Mastercraft imprint. There will be various books of various genres and each book will be able to stand on its own, fluff, mechanics and all. It's backwards compatible with Spycraft and vice-versa, which isn't being deprecated. Sorry for the slightly tardy clarification.